# Why all the project templates (but ASP.NET MVC Web Application) have disappeared from VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've done some recovery activities with my computer. Now, I've re-installed VS2008 professional edition. Unfortunately, when I right-click on the solution to add a project, the only template I'm able to see from the pop-up menu is ASP.NET MVC Web Application. Why the other templates, such as library, have disappeared? Yet, while re-installing VS2008, I've chose the full installation of all the features.

Is there any option I can use to restore them? Brief, is there anything I can do?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Before installing VS2008, I remember, I've installed ASP.NET MVC template. So, what I've just done to solve me problem was

1. To uninstall ASP.NET MVC (I could then see right away the rest of the templates)
2. Re-Install ASP.NET MVC (I still could see the other templates)

So that's it.

Thanks again